# Is there a hidden message or easter egg behind the number sequence in Star Trek The Motion Picture?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-motion-picture

At the end of the film *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* (1979), it is revealed that at the center of the massive ship, V'Ger is the Voyager 6, a 20th-century Earth space probe believed lost in a black hole. Voyager 6 attempts to communicate with the Creator in Earth.

Spock explains that V'Ger signals the Creator using a simple binary code transmitted by a radio wave signal.

In order to communicate with Voyager by triggering its transmitter, Kirk orders Uhura to obtain from ship's library records on late twentieth-century NASA probe, Voyager Six, the old NASA code signal and frequency ordering Voyager to transmit data collected. Then, Uhura transmits to V'Ger the code on appropriate frequency. The code is a number sequence as follows:

**5-0-4, 3-2-9, 3-1-7, 5-1-0,** and what is called 'the final sequence'.

I always have wondered whether if there is a hidden message/easter egg in the number sequence, or if they are just aleatory, random, stochastic numbers.

I have made my own attempts to break any potential hidden code inside the code and so far I have found very little.  For example, by adding the digits of each triad of numbers, I get the month and year of director Robert Wise's birthday date, and the month and year when the International Radiotelegraph Conference in Berlin selects "SOS" (· · · – – – · · ·) distress signal as the worldwide standard for help. Here my analysis:

5-0-4 ->   5+0+4 = 9 (September)
3-2-9 ->   3+2+9 = 14 (year 1914)

**Robert Wise was born in September 10th 1914**

3-1-7 ->   3+1+7 = 11 (November)
5-1-0 ->   5+1+0 = 6  (year 1906)

**SOS code was universally established on November 3rd 1906**

I have also tried converting the binary to ASCII as follows:

Binary code of the sequence:

**010100000100001100101001001100010111010100010000**

ASCII output:

**PC)1u**

Comment: IMDB has 253 pieces of trivia about the film.  The numerical code is mentioned only in the very last one, but there is no indication that the numbers have any meaning.

Comment: There are an almost infinite number of increasingly bizarre ways to examine a random set of digits.  The entire reason for numerology is because you can treat any set of numbers as essentially a Rorschach test.  Have you tried examining the position of the first occurrence of each triplet in the decimal expansion of π?  Or _e_?

Comment: @DavidW - No. I haven't tried that yet but V'Ger's law: "Everybody better be nice to V'Ger, or else..."

Comment: For a film made in 1979, I think ASCII and computer-related interpretations are profoundly unlikely, especially since the last character is an unprintable control character. ASCII did technically exist at that time, but the average person did not have access to a (personal) computer.

Comment: Could it be that this is genuinely one of the code sequences to communicate with Voyager 6?

Comment: @AlexPixley - Given that the real-world Voyager program ended with Voyager 2, I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Valorum:  That's what they want you to think.